# Bootstrap Accordion - Active Button

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have a Bootstrap accordion with an horizontal menu. I'm trying to change the background of the active button.

I have played a lot in JDFIDDLE without any result.

In order not to got crazy and avoid a larger mess, I did stop to claim for help.

Please check the [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/surracom/LxbwLtax/3/)

JS:

```
$("#nav2 a").on("click", function(){
   $("#nav2").find(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

CSS:

```
#nav2  a:active,
#nav2  a:hover,
#nav2  a:focus {
   color: #fff; 
   background-color: #000 !important;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're using accordion to do something it wasn't intended for. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to show the active state of the buttons. I did change the accordion behavior in order to expand the content of each collapsible just bellow the menu, It works fine. The only problem is I can't figure out how to make the active link to display a diffrent background and font.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that [tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) are more suited for what you're trying to do than accordion.

HTML:

```
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin.</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Food truck fixie locavore, accusamus mcsweeney's marfa nulla single-origin coffee squid.</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">Etsy mixtape wayfarers, ethical wes anderson tofu before they sold out mcsweeney's organic lomo retro fanny pack lo-fi farm-to-table readymade.</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">Trust fund seitan letterpress, keytar raw denim keffiyeh etsy art party before they sold out master cleanse gluten-free squid scenester freegan cosby sweater.</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j0cp4hkp/

Comment: I don´t remember why I did cast aside tabs. I'll give the another chance :) Many thanks @aross

Comment: Your sample works even without the JS piece. In my page doesn´t work. I dont find the #myTabs id in the html you provided. I'm missing something else?

Comment: Weird. It's working now, but the whole tab object is sliding up smoothly to the top of the page every time I click a tab. Any clue?

Comment: Right, I assumed it was needed as the documentation mentioned it. Removed it.

Comment: Perhaps your total HTML structure is messed up now? Make sure you completely removed the accordion stuff

Comment: It seems to have a conflict with the smooth scroll script. It looks like a new question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Solved adding href exceptions to the smooth scroll script. Well, I don't like the look of tabs, so Il give a deep look to it's css. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**JQUERY**

```
$("#headingOne a").on("click", function(){
   $(this).addClass("active");
   $("#headingOne").find('.active').not(this).removeClass("active");
});
```

I added this CSS: `.active { color:#ccc !important;}` so that you can see which menu item is active.

http://jsfiddle.net/ggChris/sqp2jkvz/